# Prolog specific element of searched sublist

Tags: prolog

Ok, i have a list of the form :

myprg(X).
X = [[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i],[j,k,l]].

that is sublists within a list.

I want to display LAST element in the sublist that has "g" as the first element.
Answer is "i"

Answer (score 0):

To be coy, here's a solution:

```
find_i([_,_,[g,_,i]|_], i).
```

That clearly works for the case you gave. Or we could make it less specific:

```
find_i([_,_,[g,_,X]|_], X).
```

Here's a slightly better one that actually does some searching:

```
find_i([[g,_,X]|_], X).
find_i([_|Rest],X) :- find_i(Rest,X).
```

Of course, it assumes the lists within will have just one item. Here's another slightly better one that doesn't:

```
find_i([[g|Rest]|_], X) :- append(_, [X], Rest).
find_i([_|Rest],     X) :- find_i(Rest, X).
```

Why are we searching for `g`? Maybe we should pull that out into its own variable:

```
find_i(G, [[G|Rest]|_], X) :- append(_, [X], Rest).
find_i(_, [_|Rest],     X) :- find_i(Rest, X).
```

This one you query like so: `find_i(g, [[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i],[j,k,l]], X)`.

A better approach would be to separate out finding the sublist and getting the last element of a list. Often in programming it helps to break things down into constituent parts like this and solve them cleanly. Like this:

```
last(L, X) :- append(_, [X], L).

find_by_first(G, [[G|Rest]|_], [G|Rest]).
find_by_first(G, [_|Rest],     Sublist) :- find_by_first(G, Rest, Sublist).

find_i(G, L, X) :- find_by_first(G, L, Sublist), last(Sublist, X).
```

Next time you should be sure to include your name and your professor's name and email address and/or the homework submission URL. Sending in the homework can also be tricky to figure out and we love to help.